# Convert.ToInt32(float) fails when trying to convert float to Int32

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, int32

No exception is thrown, function just halts at this statement:

```
int productQuantity = Convert.ToInt32("1.00");
```

and returns.

What am I doing wrong to convert this float to `Int32`?

Note: I am running in a `BackgroundWorkerThread`.

Comment: That's a string, not a float.

Comment: @NullUserException: Yes, but I have converted before if it is just "1" without the decimals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An exception is being thrown in this case it's just not being surfaced in the debugger.  This string is not in a format that is convertible to an `Int32` type and hence throws and exception.  You can verify this by wrapping it in a try/catch block if the IDE isn't cooperating.

The best approach here is probably to convert the string to a `double` and then manually cast it down to an `int`.  This does open the door for data loss due to precision differences.  But given your input is in a float style format this is unavoidable if you want the final product to be an `int`

Comment: +1 good points on the unsurfacable exception, easy to forget!

Answer (score 6):

You need to convert it to a `double` first, and then convert to `Int32`.

```
int productQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(double.Parse("1.00"));
```

Comment: with strings I recommend to always use `TryParse`, saves you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 2):

An exception is thrown, it's just that to see it you have to inspect the `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Error` property in the event handler for `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted`.

Any exception that is thrown from the background worker's thread when the background work is being done is assigned to that property.

Answer (score 0):

FormatException
Input string was not in a correct format.